# downloading email body containing inline images in java

Tags: java, email, inline-images

My issue goes as follows:

I have My code setup to read emails from a particular account. That part works perfectly.

the issue is with parsing the Email message. Separating attachments and email body(containing inline images).

My code goes like this:

```
    Void readMessages(Folder folder){

          Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
            // loading of message objects.
                for (int messageNumber = 0; messageNumber < messages.length; messageNumber++) {

             final Message currentMessage = messages[messageNumber];
                 logger.info("Handling the mail with subject " + currentMessage.getSubject());
                logger.info("Content type for the current message is " +                                  currentMessage.getContentType());
                final String messageFileName = currentMessage.getFileName();
                logger.info("File name for the message " + messageFileName + ". File name is blank "
                                                +                     StringUtils.isBlank(messageFileName));


                        Object messageContentObject = currentMessage.getContent();
                        if (messageContentObject instanceof Multipart) {
                            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) messageContentObject;

                            // downloading all attachments....
                            int attachmentCount = multipart.getCount();
                            logger.info("Number of attachments ");
                            for (int i = 0; i < attachmentCount; i++) {
                                Part part = (Part) multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                                downloadAttachment(part, folderPath.toString());
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
         private void downloadAttachment(Part part, String folderPath) throws Exception {
    String disPosition = part.getDisposition();
    String fileName = part.getFileName();
    String decodedText = null;
    logger.info("Disposition type :: " + disPosition);
    logger.info("Attached File Name :: " + fileName);

    if (disPosition != null && disPosition.equalsIgnoreCase(Part.ATTACHMENT)) {
        logger.info("DisPosition is ATTACHMENT type.");
        File file = new File(folderPath + File.separator + decodedText);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        saveEmailAttachment(file, part);
    } else if (fileName != null && disPosition == null) {
        logger.info("DisPosition is Null type but file name is valid.  Possibly inline attchment");
        File file = new File(folderPath + File.separator + decodedText);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        saveEmailAttachment(file, part);
    } else if (fileName == null && disPosition == null) {
        logger.info("DisPosition is Null type but file name is null. It is email body.");
        File file = new File(folderPath + File.separator + "mail.html");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        saveEmailAttachment(file, part);
    }


}
     protected int saveEmailAttachment(File saveFile, Part part) throws Exception {

    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    int ret = 0, count = 0;
    try {
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(saveFile));
        part.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(saveFile));

    } finally {
        try {
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            logger.error("Error while closing the stream.", ioe);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The problem i get is when i run this code, i get an HTML file but the inline images is replaced by a sign for error image which indicates the image with no source.

Please help me out with. Let me know if any more info is required.

I also tried saving the body as an `.eml` file by changing:

```
 File file = new File(folderPath + File.separator + "mail.html");
```

to

```
 File file = new File(folderPath + File.separator + "mail.eml");
```

BUt i got the same results.

Comment: "..by a sign for error image which indicates the image with no source."

Are you sure the source is empty? Have you checked the HTML source?

Comment: Check this HTML file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5evk4pjq721yo8m/mail.html

Comment: This HTML will show you the Image source missing.

Comment: The source isn't missing. It just isn't a location on the harddrive or on the web. It's a reference to another part in the multipart message. <img src="cid:ii_13b213e3157d833f" alt="Inline image 1">

Comment: Is there a way for browser to render such a thing ? Can a browser read the source from within the HTML ? If my content stream is present within the HTML. if yes, What tag is needed to identify it ?

Comment: You could save the images somewhere and replace the references in the source by the real (relative) location.

Comment: That's what i was thinking. But another point i want to know.how will we identify the replacement tag for multiple images ? for two images abc.jpeg and xyz.jpeg, HTML content is shown as [Inline: Image 1] and [Inline: Image 2]. How to identify which part is for which image ?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your solution with us? Your question is almost 1 year old.

Comment: I have not got any solution to this as yet. I later decided to let it go. I will be trying MrTux solution to see if i can get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote below code to convert email body text to pdf including inline images.
in code i replaced the image code(ex: cid:image001.jpg@01D17AAA.1EA2A6A0) with download image path.  I am constructing the "hashmap" for image key and download path while downloading the image.

```
 HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            if(bodyStr!=null)
            {

                //find inline images
                inlineImages=downloadInLineImage(mostRecentMatch, dynamicOutputDirectory);
                if(inlineImages!=null)
                {

                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : inlineImages.entrySet()) {
                        //System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
                        bodyStr=bodyStr.replaceAll("cid:"+entry.getKey() , entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
                htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(bodyStr));

        }
```

Download Inline image with passing Item.

```
 private HashMap<String,String> downloadInLineImage(Item item, String dynamicOutputDirectory)
        throws Exception, ServiceLocalException {
    //create output directory if not present

        //bind the item to a new email message. if you do not bind, then the getHasAttachments() function will fail
    EmailMessage mostRecentMatch = (EmailMessage)item;
    String from = mostRecentMatch.getFrom().getAddress();
    String user =StringUtils.substringBefore(from, "@");
    AttachmentCollection collection=item.getAttachments();

    HashMap<String,String> inlineFiles=new HashMap<String,String>();

    if(collection.getCount()>0)
    {
        for (Attachment attachment : collection.getItems()) {

            if(attachment.getIsInline())
            {

                FileAttachment currentFile = (FileAttachment) attachment;
                String filePath=dynamicOutputDirectory+"/"+user+currentFile.getName();
                File file=new File(filePath);
                FileOutputStream fio=new FileOutputStream(file);
                currentFile.load(fio);
                inlineFiles.put(currentFile.getContentId(), filePath);
                fio.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

References to inlined images are replaced by `cid:` URNs like `<img src="cid:SOMEID">`, because there are no filenames in an email. SOMEID refers to the Content-ID of the Multipart "objects".

In order to get it work, you have to store the multipart attachments to files (e.g., temporary names) and replace the `cid` URNs by the real file names.

Comment: How this is possible i have same problem. i have download inline image successfully but unable reply src:cid with my original path please give me solution if possible and as soon as possible.

Comment: Did not work for me either. Still looking for a way out.